# .NET CORE 8+hangfire 1.8.5 can't set correct dashboard language

Tags: dashboard, hangfire

I tried to use it in .NET CORE webapi 8.0 +hangfire 1.8.5 but it still shows English even though         I set Chinese in start up.
I even added culture=zh-CN to the request header, but it still doesn't work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyZnk.png)
My configuration is as follows：

```
 services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
          .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_180)
          .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
          .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
           .UseInMemoryStorage());
```

`services.AddHangfireServer();`

```
 var supportedCultures = new string[] { "zh-CN" };
 app.UseRequestLocalization(options =>
             options
             .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
             .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures)
             .SetDefaultCulture("zh-CN")
             .RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new CustomRequestCultureProvider(context =>
             {
                 return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult("zh-CN"));
             }))
     );
```

`app.UseHangfireDashboard("/job");`

Comment: There is no ".NET Core 8" - I think you mean _ASP.NET Core 8_? ?

Comment: Hangfire runs jobs in the background, outside of the context of a HTTP request, so `UseRequestLocalization` won't have any effect on it.

Comment: yes  it is ASP.NET Core 8  ,So how should I configure it properly?

Comment: Why are you using Hangfire at all, though?